# Apache mod_autoindex and declaring a favicon in the <head>?

Tags: apache-2.2, html, favicon

All browsers are not equal. Hence I need to explicitly state that I have a favicon ("shortcut icon") for `mod_autoindex`-generated pages. How can I do that?

Using header (`HeaderName`) and footer (`ReadmeName`) is not an option because those get included into the HTML-body. I need to manipulate the `<head>` part of the generated HTML.

**Edit 1:**
The first reply states to use `/favicon.ico`. This is not a solution either, because as I stated above not all browsers request that file automagically. I have a very stubborn Firefox 8.0 here that refuses to load it for example. This can be seen in the server logs (missing HTTP request for that *existing and readable* file - yes, it works in Opera, for example) and and in FF itself (with the Live HTTP headers addin). No HTTP request to the server, which cannot logically be explained with the `/favicon.ico` not being readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the *`IndexOptions +SuppressHTMLPreamble`* option to the *.htaccess* file to suppress *mod_autoindex*'s automatic injection of the preambulatory *`<html><head></head><body>`* tags and then include those tags and your desired *`<link>`* tag in your *Header.html* file.

This option is available in Apache 1.3 and later.

Answer (score 2):

All browsers request "/favicon.ico" at least once when you visit a web host.

Just create it.

Comment: Actually they don't. I have a very stubborn Firefox 8.0 here that refuses to behave as you say. Can be seen both in the server logs and FF itself (with the Live HTTP headers addin). I'll edit that into my question, as I was aware of Opera doing that request on `/favicon.ico`.

Comment: That means it could not read the file. Fix the file permissions.

Comment: Right, so the file permissions on the server are responsible that the browser doesn't even request the file in the first place? Don't think so! What's wrong with the nickname?

Comment: I just visited Google.com in FF8, which specifies no favourites icon, and it fetched `/favicon.ico` just fine. Fix your broken FF install first.

Comment: @ceejayoz: thank you. It's not a broken installation but rather one of the add-ons. I disabled all but Live HTTP headers and voila it works. I'll accept the response, but will probably edit it with the details of the add-on causing this effect.